# Windows Hello Fingerprint Enrollment in C#

Tags: c#, authentication, fingerprint, credential-providers, windows-hello

I didn't enroll for windows hello in settings(sign-in-options) and Now I want to load the windows hello enrollment UI by using `RequestCreateAsync("String", KeyCredentialCreationOption.ReplaceExisting)` API in C#. But the response is taking the value has Null. Can any one please let me know is it possible to load the windows hello enrollment UI?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check the parameter's values you are passing to the function.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this solution https://github.com/JcBernack/WinBioNET
I've solved my all Windows Hello questions with this project.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: if you have any questions, be sure to ask :)